# Laravel translate values required_if

Tags: laravel, translate

I am using Laravel version 5.2.45. Currently I have some troubles with translating required_if rule.
When I am using the required_if,field,value it's printing out the fields value in the error validation message, which in this case is either 1 or 0. that is not very readable.

**For example:**

Field 1 is required if type is 0

**Would like:**

Field 1 is required if type is default

Is there any way to translate the values of the rquired_if value/:value?

Controller:

```
$customerVal = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'field1' => 'required_if:type,0',
        'field2' => 'required_if:type,0',
    ]);
```

View:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="modalMsg alert">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
```

I can see that Laravel has this in the language section:

```
'required_if'          => ':attribute is required when :other are  :value.',
```

So it's basically :value I need to translate(dynamically).
I have tried below, but that does not replace 0:

```
'attributes' => [
'field1' => [
            '0' => 'test'
        ]
]
```

Answer (score 10):

You are trying to translate *values* rather than *attributes*.

Open `app/lang/en/validation.php` file and add new array element:

```
'values' => [
    'type' => [
        '0' => 'default',
     ],
 ],
```

Found in [laravel's github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4037).

Comment: Thanks! Also now documented at https://laravel.com/docs/validation#specifying-values-in-language-files