# Laravel - How to translate validation values? Not possible?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is a similar question and info what this is all about:
[Laravel translate values required_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139131/laravel-translate-values-required-if)

And here's GitHub gist of feature which would solve this problem and it is merged in but still not working:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4037

Here are my validation rules

```php
'input.deliver_to_address' => ['in:to_billing_address,to_other_address']
'input.delivery_company_name' => ['required_if:input.deliver_to_address,to_other_address'],
```

and here's my `validation.php` files:

```php
'values' => [
        'to_other_address' => 'to other address',
        'input.deliver_to_address' => [
            'to_other_address' => 'to other address',
        ],
        'deliver_to_address' => [
            'to_other_address' => 'to other address',
        ],
    ],
```

As you can see I've tried all possible combinations but still the validation rule displays:

`The contact person field is required when deliver to address is to_other_address.`

The question is, is it possible to translate array validation values in Laravel?

I'm using Laravel 6.2

Comment: This is interesting. When diving into the source code, it looks like its all good. But still, for some reason, the key is returned instead of the value.

Comment: Okay, the deeper I go the more convinced I'm that this is a bug. It would be cool to hear if this feature actually works on someone.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved:**

The issue was that I'm using `input.deliver_to_address` and when the `Validator.php` tries to replace the value with translated string, the `$key` will be `validation.values.input.deliver_to_address.to_other_address`

so the array structure needs to be like this:

```php
'values' => [
        'input' => [
            'deliver_to_address' => [
                'to_other_address' => 'to other address',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

instead of

```php
'values' => [
        'input.deliver_to_address' => [
            'to_other_address' => 'to other address',
        ],
    ],
```

because of the additional `.input` in the attribute name.